# Two options bar button item

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

[image: Button example]

Maybe not so smart question but how i could make such close to each other, one on - other off type of buttons?

Comment: With a `UISegmentedControl`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really vague, but if I get you right you're looking for the Segmented Control which can be found under objects in the interface builder.. You can add this to your UIToolBar just like the UIBarButtonItem :)

Fiddle with the options and check the documentation for more info..

-V

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's a `UISegmentedControl`, that you can find when you are creating your XIB, here:

[image]

You can also find some neat stuff [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Segmented), where you can find some custom `UISegmentedControls`.

Answer (score 2):

Best thing you can use is `UISegmentedControl` A segmented control displays a list of options that a user can choose from. Each segment sort of looks like a button; the segments remains “pressed” even after the user lifts his or her finger.
for more details [for more details](http://mobileappmastery.com/here-is-how-you-use-uisegmentedcontrol/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a UISegmented control, it accomplished what you want to do.
Check the references...

[Reference 1](http://mobisoftinfotech.com/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/)

[Reference 2](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/29597-uisegmentedcontrol-tutoria.html)